# animated GIF featured image wordpress

Tags: wordpress, animation, gif, animated-gif

I want to use an animated gif as my featured image in WordPress (div, theme). I read a lot about the problems using animated gifs in WordPress, so I chose "large/full size" for the gif file and it works fine on a 13" screen. But on mobile devices, it doesn't resize to the smaller screen width. It stays at 1278px width and therefore gets cropped out.

How do I make the animated gif for all devices work so it keeps it's animation and still fits within the screen width?

Answer (score 0):

use css:

```
img{max-width:100% !important;}
```

hope it will help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.